# Set any external value in a model from view page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have to set @item.ID in model, as in given code I am setting Amount in EditorFor(model => model.Amount).I have to save that amount and ID in database so both should be post in my action of controller.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.countries)
{              
  <td><label class="control-label">@item.Name</label></td>                                              
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)</td>
  <td><input type="text" /></td>
  <td><button type="submit" class="btn-primary</i>Update</button></td>               
}
```

My Model is:--

```
public class AllocationViewModel
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public long CountryId { get; set; }
    }
```

Here I have to set countryID in model from item.ID of viewbag.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I have to post @item.ID as model.CountryID from viewpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `model.CountryId` in a hidden field for each item, so you can post it to server.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.countries)
{              
  <td><label class="control-label">@item.Name</label></td>                                              
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)</td>
  <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountryId, new { @Value = item.ID })</td>
  <td><input type="text" /></td>
  <td><button type="submit" class="btn-primary</i>Update</button></td>               
}
```

Comment: I have to set item.ID which is coming through Viewbag.countries in model.

Comment: I am getting compilation error while using HiddenFor

Comment: @user3206357, Yeah correct, you need to add the `Id` property in your model. Can you please show your model class? Also let me know, will the `item.ID` will be vary for all?